# Remote Angular2 server hanging while serving development build

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using a remote server for development of an Angular app (v4.4.3). The server is being served remotely for development and being accessed through a local browser. I.e.

```
ng serve --host URL --port 8080
```

It produces the following output:

```
Hash: 4691491fe6185644edc3                                                          Time: 10717ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 183 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 12 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 147 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.49 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

Sometimes, it will start failing to load on the client:

```
GET http://[URL]:8080/vendor.bundle.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
> Uncaught TypeError: ...
```

This then persists. Sometimes, changing the code cause it to start working again. It goes away if I create a new project and copy the old files across, rebuilding it from scratch. It has happened on a number of projects, including the Tour of Heroes tutorial. Building the project for production and serving it via Apache works without any problems.

I'm not doing anything special with the app, or loading any particular node packages. From what I can tell, it happens randomly. It seems to be caused by timing out while trying to download the bundles and not having loaded everything (thus having a mismatch of content length).

I have tried the following things:

- [Flushing `node_modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351273/neterr-content-length-mismatch-on-angular-2-on-docker-cloud#45008438)
- Reverting to a previous version of the project (git)
- Restarting the server

It is not caused by the following:

- [Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661058/neterr-content-length-mismatch-on-nginx-1-8-0) (it was working fine before a minor change)
- [Nginx in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212134/an-error-configuring-nginx-with-angular-2-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-con) (I'm not using it?)
- [Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124262/err-content-length-mismatch-node-express-angular)

The only two things it could possibly be are:

- My server, but it *only* has this problem with Angular
- Angular, but I have no idea where. I've essentially reset it through a `git checkout` to an older, functioning version.

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this problem and tried a few steps to get it working again.

1. Revert a few recent changes: New imports, new features, but only stuff that changed since the error started appearing.
2. Restart your Server. Restart your Browser.

The second one worked for me. I hope you'll get it working!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can confirm that none of this helps.

Comment: Very unfortunate indeed - it worked for me after I restarted the browser window. Please let me know if you find any solution, it might be useful in the future.

Comment: For me, refreshing the site typically works after 2-4 attempts. If it doesn't then I try restarting the server, which typically works 50% of the time. Would be nice if there was a proper fix for this issue.